# Are There Always Group Generators Which Give Unimodal Growth?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a $k$-generated finite group.  Is there always a set of $k$ elements which generate the group and have a unimodal counting function?

**Background:**
The counting function, $f(n)$, is a function whose value at $n$ is the number  of elements of $G$ of length $n$.

The length of an element $x$, relative to a given generating set, is the length of the shortest word, made up only of elements of the generating set, which is equal to $x$. We don't use the inverses of elements of the generating set for the purpose of determining length in this discussion.

A unimodal sequence is a finite sequence that first increases, and then decreases. A sequence $\{s_1, s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$ is unimodal if there exists a $t$ such that $s_1\leq s_2\leq\cdots\leq s_t$, and $s_t \geq s_{t+1} \geq \cdots\geq s_n$. (Weisstein, Eric W. "Unimodal Sequence." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnimodalSequence.html)

**Discussion:**
As pointed out in one of the comments, taking $k$ to be the number of elements in the group will trivially give unimodal growth.  The question is more interesting if one considers values of k which are less than the number of elements in the group.  In a search that I made of some finite groups there was always a set of generators for which the counting function was unimodal.  In fact, nonunimodal growth was a rarity.  This may just be consequence of the fact that I looked only at groups with a small number of elements.  I'm convinced that for commutative groups any choice of generators will yield a unimodal counting function.

Here is an example of a group with non-unimodal growth. The two generators are the permutations:

$a = \{7, 9, 2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 8, 4\}$

$b = \{6, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9\}$

In this notation $a$ is the permutation which takes 1 into 7, 2 into 9, 3 into 2,...

The counting function for this pair of generators is:

1,2,4,8,13,21,33,44,55,75,83,80,85,65,39,27,11,2.

Comment: What is an example of a group and set of generators with nonunimodal growth?

Comment: In the special case of finite Coxeter groups with their standard generators unimodality should be well-known, e.g. for the Weyl groups it follows from hard Lefschetz applied to flag varieties.

Comment: For a finite Coxeter group of rank $n$ (crystallographic or not) with simple generators $S$ and reflections $T$, the length generating functions are known to be $(1+q+\ldots+q^{e_1}) \cdots (1+q+\ldots+q^{e_n})$ and $(1+e_1q)\cdots(1+e_nq)$ where $e_i$ are the exponents of the group. This implies unimodality in both cases.

Comment: Should k always be the minimal number of generators?  If you use the whole group as generators than trivially you have unimodality.

Comment: @Douglas Zare  I've added an example of a group and two of its generators for which the counting function is not unimodal.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg  I've added a comment that the conjecture is trivially true if k is taken to be the number of elements in the group.

Comment: @David: your definition of unimodal is not the same as in Wikipedia. Is the sequence $(1,2,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,\dots)$ unimodal for your definition (which confuses me: do you mean that the set on which $f$ is maximal is an integral interval? no monotonous behavior as in Wikipedia's definition?)

Comment: @YvesCornulier By my definition 1,2,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,.... is not unimodal.  It has two local maxima:2 and 3.  The sequence 1,2,3,3,0,0,0,... is unimodal by my definition.  It has a single maximum: 3, although 3 appears more than once, its appearances come for successive values of f.  The sequence 1,2,3,2,3,... would not meet my definition of unimodal.  Although the only maximum is 3, its two appearances are separated by the value 2.  I haven't looked at the Wikipedia definition, but I'd guess that it deals with functions on a continuous domain.  Here we have values for f only at integers.

Comment: Your definition above does not talk about local maxima, but about a global maximum. @YvesCornulier sequence does thus fit your definition of unimodality.

Comment: @David: no, it just means you forgot the word "local" in your definition. Then your definition coincides with Wikipedia's (which concerns sequences, otherwise I wouldn't have mentioned it).

Comment: @YvesCornulier  I've changed the definition of unimodal to correspond to that in MathWorld. Thanks.

Comment: The counting function I obtain for the generators you give is $(1, 2, 4, 8, 14, 23, 37, 52, 69, 98, 120, 132, 114)$, which is unimodal. Can you get in touch so we can figure out who's right and why?

Comment: @Anthony Labarre  I am away from my computer for the next few days.  Hopefully when I get back I'll be able to find my computations in my Mathematica files.  If I have to redo the computations it will take me a substantially longer time.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre  I couldn't wait and did the calculations by hand.  For words of length 4, (which is the first case where we disagree) using "a" for one  permutation and "b" for the other, I find that aaaa = bbbb = the identity, while aabb = bbaa.  Then, by my count, there are 16-3 = 13 words of length 4.  Is this of some help?

Comment: @DavidS.Newman Yes, this allowed me to find the flaw in my script, and the sequence I obtain is now identical to yours, thank you! Is $n=9$ the smallest value for which you found a counterexample?

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Yes.  I believe that these permutations of length 9 were the shortest permutations that I found which give non-unimodal growth.  However, I don't think that I did an exhaustive search.  I think I took arbitrary permutations and then calculated the counting function for these pairs.

Answer (score 3):

In response to the bounty question:

By the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, any finite $k$-generated abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to the lattice $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{k} \mathbb{Z}_{r_i}$ for prime powers $r_1, \ldots, r_k$. Then $f(n)$ is the number of solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{i} = n$ in the integers $0 \leq x_i \leq r_i-1$. This is equal to the coefficient of $t^n$ in the generating function
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1 + t + \ldots + t^{r_i -1}) .
$$
Any polynomial of this form is unimodal, as (I think) Christian Stump alluded to in his comment. Stanley proves this fact in Proposition 1 of this article:

http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/72.pdf .